# @font-face doesn't work

Tags: css, fonts

Adding this to the style.css works:

```
* { font-family: "Courier New", Courier, monospace; }
```

Probably because Courier New is widely popular and supported. However, using this on my custom font doesn't work:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'new-baskerville';
    font-style: normal;
    src: url('/wp-content/uploads/useanyfont/190811081519New-Baskerville.eot');
    src: local('new-baskerville'), url('/wp-content/uploads/useanyfont/190811081519New-Baskerville.eot') format('embedded-opentype'), url('/wp-content/uploads/useanyfont/190811081519New-Baskerville.woff') format('woff');
}
```

Or chaning `@font-face` to `*` doesn't work either. The files do exist in the path. Do you know why is that?

Comment: You either have to work with an absolute URL or get the relative URL right, as the style sheet probably isn't in the document root of your WP installation. CSS questions are generally off-topic on [wordpress.se], please take a look at the [help] to get familiar with the site guidelines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This article](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/using-font-face/) has some very helpful information regarding `@font-face`, and compatibility issues ... just in case.

Here are some potential improvements in your @font-face section:

- One of your src entries lists "local".  Try removing that.
- Try using explicit addressing for your files.
- Make sure you can actually open your font files, or at least do not get a 404 Error.
- Try listing your files as I have, with two src entries: one for IE and one for modern browsers.
- See if your font files provide a TTF file for Safari and mobile browsers.

`

```
@font-face {    font-family: 'newBaskerville';
    src: url('https://{your-domain}.com/wp-content/uploads/useanyfont/190811081519New-Baskerville.eot');
    src: url('https://{your-domain}.com/wp-content/uploads/useanyfont/190811081519New-Baskerville.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
    url('https://{your-domain}.com/wp-content/uploads/useanyfont/190811081519New-Baskerville.woff') format('woff'); 
}
```

Finally, apply the font to your body with fallback styles, like you have in your Courier example above:

```
body{ font-family: "newBaskerville", Courier, monospace; }
```

**note:**  Be sure to use the same name when applying the name as you did when defining it.  In my case "newBaskerville", to avoid any issues with spaces and/or punctuation.

Comment: If you cannot open or download your font files through the browser's address bar, you should ensure your server is configured with the proper mime types, as I suggested in your other Question thread, for this same issue.

Comment: thank you so much. Do you know why `@font-face` alone cannot change the font, and `body` needs to be specify? What about other font variation files, like bold or italic? Also, is there a way to tell a text inserted directly in header.php to use this setting? And do you know how to use the font when editing posts?